# Pandas: Concatenating column names depending on value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a table as follows:

```
    a   b   c   d   e
r1  0   1   0   1   0
r2  1   1   0   0   0
```

I want to create a column f that is a concatenation of column names only if the row has a value of 1.

```
So [r1,f] = bd and [r2,f] = ab
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to do this with pandas? Would appreciate any help at all!

Comment: Are in dataframe only `0` and `1` values, or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple columns names by `df` by [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) and then [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) - but in `df` are `0` and `1` values which are converted to `True`s and `False`s:

```
df['f'] = df.mul(df.columns.values).sum(axis=1)
print (df)
    a  b  c  d  e   f
r1  0  1  0  1  0  bd
r2  1  1  0  0  0  ab
```

General solutions (if more possible values as `0`, `1`):

Add [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) for compare with `1`:

```
df['f'] = df.eq(1).mul(df.columns.values).sum(axis=1)
print (df)
    a  b  c  d  e   f
r1  0  1  0  1  0  bd
r2  1  1  0  0  0  ab
```

Solution with `dot` and `eq`:

```
df['f'] = df.eq(1).dot(df.columns.values)
print (df)
    a  b  c  d  e   f
r1  0  1  0  1  0  bd
r2  1  1  0  0  0  ab
```

Another solution with `apply` is slowier:

```
df['f'] = df.apply(lambda x: ''.join(x.index[x == 1]), axis=1)
print (df)
    a  b  c  d  e   f
r1  0  1  0  1  0  bd
r2  1  1  0  0  0  ab
```

EDIT:

For adding space is possible use:

```
df['f'] = df['f'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(list(x)))
print (df)
    a  b  c  d  e    f
r1  0  1  0  1  0  b d
r2  1  1  0  0  0  a b
```

Comment: Wow that is amazing! thank you so much! How do I include a space in between? Like instead of bd, display "b d"?

Comment: Hmm, then need `df['f'] = df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.index[x == 1]), axis=1)`

Comment: @piRSquared - I add comment under question. But simple it depends of data. If `0,1` only, is it not necesary.

Comment: Done! Thank you so much Jezrael!

Comment: @tlhy - Glad can help!